# Devise User Profile link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, user-interface, devise

So I am currently trying to figure out what path to use so when the user clicks on 'View Profile' the link will be domain.com/USERNAME instead of domain.com/profiles/show

My current code for the link is

```
<li><%= link_to "View Profile", profiles_show_path %></li>
```

my routes.rb is set at

```
get '/:id' to: 'profiles#show'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify an user as parameter in your link:

```
<li><%= link_to "View Profile", profile_path(user) %></li>
```

In your routes:

```
get '/:id', to: 'profiles#show', as: :profile
```

So you're overriding the default `profile_path()`.